# Silverlight Form is freezing

Tags: javascript, silverlight, user-interface, freeze

i am calling ~250 Javascript synchronous webservices in a loop in silverlight. This needs about 3 minutes to complete. in this time, my form is freezing and the user cant do any input and my progressbar dont update the value.
This part is in the loop. the function "Unshare" do the webservice request

```
 object ret = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("Unshare", acc.ToString(), SelectedUser.ToString());

            if (ret != null)
            {
                bool tmpBool;
                if (Boolean.TryParse(ret.ToString(), out tmpBool))
                {
                    if (tmpBool)
                    {
                        IncreaseProgress(false);
                    }
                }
            }
```

_

```
private void IncreaseProgress(bool isError)
    {

            FinishedAccounts++;
            label_total.Content = string.Format("Total: {0} / {1}", FinishedAccounts, Accounts.Count);
            progressBar1.Value += this.ProgressStep;
            if (isError)
            {
                Errors++;
                label_error.Content = string.Format("Error: {0}", Errors);
            }
    }
```

how can i update the gui after each request? at the moment the gui freezes and after the ~250 webservice requests the gui is updated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Alex, this is quite interesting problem. When you process something on UI it uses UI main thread which respond to UI events too. When this thread is busy doing your 250 request it can't server UI events and it will be not be responsive. I don't know why you need sync calls when you are using Web service you can make it Async. If you still want to use this you can use BackGroundWorker thread which will not use UI thread and your UI will not be freezed

Comment: Hi vinod, thank you for your awnser. i need sync requests, because i get sql generic errors if i do it asynchronous. can i call a javascript from another thread as the ui thread? i mean like this: htmlpage.window.invoke(). I will try it

Comment: If i do the loop for the requests in javascript and call a silverlight methode from javascript to update the ui, would it work without freezing?

Comment: no this will also freeze the UI because Javascript will also use UI thread..